# UTM parameters not set for my website with Firebase dynamic links

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links, utm

I have a need to shorten my website url and I choose Firebase Dynamic Links (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) for that. I also added UTM parameters while creating the link.

When clicked on the link, the user is redirected to the desired website, but these parameters are not getting passed to it. Hence by GA for the website doesn't track it.

Am I doing something wrong? Or Is Dynamic Links a bad choice for my use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTM parameters that you choose in UI are parameters for mobile tracking. If you want to pass UTM parameters to your "fallback" website, you need to add them to the fallback address itself.

So to be covered in all cases you'd need to add UTM parameters in UI configuration (or as normal UTM parameters) and inside fallback link, for example:

Let's say those are your UTM params: 
`utm_campaign=spring_sale&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google`

Your current link:

> https://sample.page.link/?link=http://example.com?utm_campaign%3Drandom&apn=com.demo.firebase&**utm_campaign=spring_sale&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google**

Your new link with UTM embedded in web link (https://example.com?utm_campaign=spring_sale&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google):

> https://sample.page.link/?link=https://example.com?**utm_campaign%3Dspring_sale%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_source%3Dgoogle**&apn=com.demo.firebase&**utm_campaign=spring_sale&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google**

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestion and it works now.